# Shortcut for adding UIView in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, shortcut, hotkeys

Is there anybody who knows how to create shortcut for adding UIView to Storyboard?
Or is it possible to create user's shortcuts for custom actions in Xcode? Or maybe it's already exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this shortcut ⇧+option+⌘+L to open the Library fast and you can drag it from there

You can also use bettertouchtool to add an action when doing a specific shortcut or tapping a button on the touchbar to do this:

⇧+option+⌘+L and typing then UIView

Comment: I like this answer with using Touch Bar, good idea. Need new Mac)

Answer (score 2):

For me works with ⌘+⇧+L.
option is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add shortcuts using Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings. Search for the command-name using the field at the top-right, then double click in the key field and type the key you want to use.

But other than predefined commands not sure if you can add custom ones.